# In my application, a spinner item selection is mandatory. How can I show an error to the user if the user doesn't select any item?

Tags: android, validation, spinner

I want to show an error message in `Spinner`, stating the user to "select a state" when the user doesn't make any selection in the spinner (selecting `spinner item` is mandatory).

How can I do that with the `Mainactivity.java` code?

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"  
        android:layout_width="319dp" 
        android:layout_height="52dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" 
        android:entries="@array/state_arrays"/>
```

Comment: So far, what you've tried. Kindly share your code to help u.

Comment: instead of posting on comment, add above xml in your question by editing.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate a spinner with the `.equals()` method. Try the below code:

```
if (Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("select a city")) {
    Toast.makeText(CallWs.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Work like charm!.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below function to validate that `spinner` contains your default text.

```
 public static boolean validateSpinner(AppCompatSpinner[] fields) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            AppCompatSpinner currentField = fields[i];
            if (currentField.getCount() <= 0 || currentField.getSelectedItem().toString().contains("Your Default Value")) {
                ((TextView) currentField.getSelectedView()).setError(fieldRequired);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If the spinner has selected any of the drop down items, it returns `true`, else `false`.

```
 if (!validateSpinner(new AppCompatSpinner[]{citySpinner}))
             Utils.showSnackbar(mainLayout, selectCityTxt);
```

Add this line where you want to validate `spinner`.

Instead of showing `Toast`, the `validateSpinner()` function will create a dynamic `textview` to show the error message.